# How do I create and render a custom region?

Tags: theming, display-suite

How do I create and render a custom region in Drupal 7, when the Display Suite module is used?
I am not able to show/display a block into a custom region and  confused with the files structure. Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution and so sharing with all, if it could help someone:

Creating a custom region in our theme if we are using display suite module is slightly different.

1.First define region in your theme's .info file (same as we do without display suite)

```
regions[name_of_region] = 'Name of Region'
```

2.Then print the following line in your template file wherever you want to display

```
print render(block_get_blocks_by_region('name_of_region'));
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom region, I found I needed to add my region (called `customregion`) to the .module file:

```
$layouts['bootstrap_3_9'] = array(
  .......
  'regions' => array(
    'left' => t('Left'),
    'right' => t('Right'),
    'customregion' => t('Custom Region'),
  ),
  .......
);
```

and then just reference it in template:

```
<?php print $customregion; ?>
```